# In Linux I'd use "/opt" for custom software. In FreeBSD?

Tags: software-installation, freebsd, directory-structure

Where should I install "add-on application software packages" or "for software not managed by the system packager"? That is, software compiled by myself from sources or what-not.

In Linux I'd choose `/opt`. What about in FreeBSD?

Answer (score 5):

Using `/opt` would be a good option in most Unices that doesn't use it for anything else.

FreeBSD will not touch `/opt` with it's base system and it's using `/usr/local` for its packages.

See also [the Directory Structure section in FreeBSD handbook](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/dirstructure.html) (where `/opt` isn't mentioned at all).